# mlr equivalent of carets model selectionFunction in R

Tags: r, r-caret, mlr

The caret library in R has a hyper-parameter 'selectionFunction' inside trainControl().
It's used to prevent over-fitting models using Breiman's one standard error rule, or tolerance, etc.

Does mlr have an equivalent? If so, which function is it within?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Posting an answer to my own question, I found [this.](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/estimateRelativeOverfitting.html).

#### Estimate relative overfitting.

Source: [`R/relativeOverfitting.R`](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/blob/master/R/relativeOverfitting.R)

Estimates the relative overfitting of a model as the ratio of the difference in test and train performance to the difference of test performance in the no-information case and train performance. In the no-information case the features carry no information with respect to the prediction. This is simulated by permuting features and predictions.

```
estimateRelativeOverfitting(
  predish,
  measures,
  task,
  learner = NULL,
  pred.train = NULL,
  iter = 1
)
```

**Arguments**

- **predish** - ([ResampleDesc](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/makeResampleDesc.html) [ResamplePrediction](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/ResamplePrediction.html) [Prediction](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/Prediction.html)) Resampling strategy or resampling prediction or test predictions.
- **measures** - ([Measure](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/makeMeasure.html) list of [Measure](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/makeMeasure.html)) Performance measure(s) to evaluate. Default is the default measure for the task, see here [getDefaultMeasure](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/getDefaultMeasure.html).
- **task** - ([Task](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/Task.html)) The task.
- **learner** - ([Learner](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/makeLearner.html)  `character(1)`) The learner. If you pass a string the learner will be created via [makeLearner](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/makeLearner.html).
- **pred.train** - ([Prediction](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/Prediction.html)) Training predictions. Only needed if test predictions are passed.
- **iter** - ([integer](https://rdrr.io/r/base/integer.html)) Iteration number. Default 1, usually you don't need to specify this. Only needed if test predictions are passed.

Answer (score 2):

*mlr* only allows to choose optimal hyperparameters by optimizing certain measures/metrics.

However, essentially each "measure" in *mlr* is just a function that specifies how a certain performance is handled.
You can try to write your own custom measure as outlined in [this vignette](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/create_measure.html).

Other than that, it might be worth opening this as a feature request in the new *mlr3* framework, specifically in [mlr3measures](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3measures),  since *mlr* itself is deprecated.